# link directly to google rating popup

Tags: hyperlink

I need to link to googles ajax rating popup. For example searching for [google](https://www.google.de/search?q=google%20bewertungen%20&oq=google%20bewertungen%20&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59l2j0l3.3956j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=google%20germany&lrd=lrd) and then clicking "Bericht schreiben" or "write report". A popup will appear now - how can I link to this popup? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

1st You need to register to Google Places for Business..
https://www.google.com/business/placesforbusiness/

I don't think you link to that modal window but maybe google have an api for reviews etc..